# General solution to homogeneous difference equation

Tags: functional-equations

With a given example

$$ a_{n-1} = ca_{n-2} $$

general solution:

$$ a_{n} = c . c . a_{n-2} $$
$$       = c . c . a_{n-3} $$
$$       = c^n a_0 $$

Question: Find the general solution for the homogeneous equation
$$ a_{n} = 5a_{n-1} $$

General solution:

$$ a_{n} = 5^n a_{0} $$

Is my general solution correct based on the given example?

Comment: I believe you have a typo in the first equation, should it be $a_n = c \cdot a_{n-1}$?

Comment: Yes. There is a typo in the first displayed formula, you meant $a_n=c\cdot a_{n-1}$, and in the third displayed line, you meant $a_n=c\cdot c\cdot c\cdot  a_{n-3}$.  And I would prefer to go forwards than backwards, $a_1=5a_0$, $a_2=5a_1=5^2a_0$, and so on.  But backwards is fine.

Comment: @Nicolas Villanueva: I have corrected the typo. 
@yunone: I am new to mathse. Thanks for the info. I will accept the answers

Comment: @liangneh: The correction of the first typo should have been to $a_n=c\cdot a_{n-1}$.  The correction you made is correct, but not as helpful.  The next typo, on the third displayed line, remains uncorrected as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if that first equation is a typo, that is the correct general solution. If a proof is necessary, I suggest using Induction on $n$.

Comment: That was a given example for me to answer the question below.

Comment: this is not a proving question